# Deployment error with Permission sets

Tags: deployment, migration-tool, permission-sets

I have 2 permission sets and when i try to deploy to another sandbox, i get the below error

```
Error Message
Process_Builder_Permission  Permission Set  0   0   Permission View All Data depends on permission(s): Read All QuickText, Read All ScorecardAssociation, Read QuickText, Read ScorecardAssociation

Regional_Business_Support   Permission Set  0   0   Permission View All Data depends on permission(s): Read All QuickText, Read All ScorecardAssociation, Read QuickText, Read ScorecardAssociation
```

They both have the '`View All Data`' checked. And from the error msg, it looks like i need to enable the below as well:

```
1. Read All QuickText, 
2. Read All ScorecardAssociation, 
3. Read QuickText, 
4. Read ScorecardAssociation
```

Where do i find these options? Although 1,2 & 3,4 looks the same

Comment: Okay - i have found the settings QuickText and ScorecardAssociation, in the permissionset

Answer (score 0):

I just need to enable both `QuickText` and `ScorecardAssociation` for the `permissionSets` in both the source and target sandboxes